# Here's a question in an interesting state

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

[Consider this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666160/odd-behavior-when-recursively-building-a-return-type-for-variadic-functions) It's been building up votes for weeks, but it is most definitely not attracting answers. The comment trail suggests that's it's just a plain old bug in the compiler. None of the commenters seem to be inclined to turn their remarks into an answer, so, there it sits: right at the top of the unanswered list, advertising the apparent inability of the site to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

I think litb put it very well,

> Good lord, that's a lot to read :) – Johannes Schaub - litb  Apr 19 at 20:28

If the question absolutely *requires* all that information in order to answer it, then it's probably going to sit there until an expert comes along, gets interested in it, and solves the problem.

However, I suspect that a several very short questions would more likely reach the correct conclusion.

Further, in the question itself, the author states that his query is merely of a curious nature, he's resolved the issue for his own application:

> Ultimately, I've gotten past the problem, with a fairly elegant solution that hardly resembles either of the first two attempts. So I know how to do what I want to do. I'm looking for an explanation for the failure I saw.

So only those that

- Read the entire thing
- Understand the new features of c++0x
- Understand GCC internals
- Have sufficient time and curiosity to figure out the issue knowing it is of little practical use

will even consider approaching the problem.

Lastly, I've found that I get much more response if I do a teaser question.  It turns out that if you draw people in with a very short, simple question that strikes at the heart of the problem (maybe with a very short (2-4 line) code snippet that shows the problem), then you'll get a ton of people interested enough to ask detail questions.  Further, since I'm not sharing my assumptions, they will be very well questioned.

Turns out a lot of my "superhard" questions are merely poor assumptions I can't even see that I'm making.

But by getting people invested in the question, I can then travel down the path with them, even though I've already gone down that path, and they can show me new avenues of solutions, and will spend a lot more time on my problem than they do if I lay it all out for them in a 2 page summary of the issue.

So litb is largely right - too long *is* a problem here.

Comment: That question made my head hurt, prior to understanding what he was actually doing. Nothing more to see there, move along, move along (for me, anyway).

Comment: ....and with that last edit I've officially moved into tldr territory.  Oh the irony!

Answer (score 0):

It actually has 3 answers, but they are all deleted for various reasons.

Seeing as how the question is highly specific and no one can seem to reproduce the problem, I guess people may be upvoting (possibly out of sympathy) because the question was at least complete and well-written, and *potentially* useful to someone else who runs aground of the same bug.

Comment: 1) misunderstanding, 2) joke, 3) spam - so they aren't instructive at all.